# Which IP Ranges has to be whitelisted inorder to use workbench

Tags: workbench, ip

IP restriction are enabled in our org. when i try to access workbench i get a invalid_IP login error.What range of IP addresses has to be white listed and how safe can white-listing those IP addresses be?

Answer (score 2):

This is mentioned in [KB 000214031](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000214031&type=1):

> ## Security concern about Workbench's source IP addresses
>
> Workbench is NOT a supported product of or supported by Salesforce.com, inc. This application is hosted on Heroku and as a result it's IP address will be that of Amazon Web Services.
>
> workbench.developerforce.com is hosted on Heroku and thereby on AWS (Amazon Web Services), which uses the IP ranges documented at https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json, instead of the IP addresses used by Salesforce servers.
>
> If this is a concern, you may consider configuring workbench within a firewall server in your company's network and use the source code and instructions found in this GitHub repository:
>   https://github.com/ryanbrainard/forceworkbench. Alternatively, if you are an existing Heroku customer, you may run this app on your own Heroku instance.
>
> Please note that Workbench is NOT a supported product of or supported by Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

Type login in Quick Find in Setup and click 'Login History'.

Then you can see the IP address of the failed login attempt from Workbench:

[image]

Also remember to check that login from test.salesforce.com is not disabled -

Type ‘Domain’ in Quick Find, click ‘My Domain' and make sure it is unchecked:

[image]